# C# array pathfinding for a tower defense game

Tags: c#, arrays

so i have an array displaying zeros and ones like this, which makes a level:

```
int[,] map = new int[,]
    {
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}, // The level of the game in an array
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}, // zeroes relate to a grass texture
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}, // ones are path textures
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    };
```

currently i have enemies following this array by using hard coded waypoints like the one shown below:

```
waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(2, 0) * 40);
```

i was wondering if there was a way to tell the enemies to follow the "1"s without hardcoding the waypoints so that i could implement a custom map editor into my game and the enemies would always know to follow the ones in the array

Comment: If you know the enemy's current location, examine the 4 adjacent spots in the matrix (8 if you include diagonals) and find the one which is a 1. You'll need to make a decision about which one to follow if there's multiple 1s, but once you've picked a location, subtract the indices for the new location from the current location, and instruct the enemy to move in that direction.

Comment: You'd have to consider some sort of loop or recursive function that considered all of the immediate neighbours of the current element; when a "1" is found, move to that element and repeat, being sure to consider the previous element so you don't get stuck infinitely going back and forth between the two.

Comment: When you load the map, you can compute the "moves" to be done by the enemies in another array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cell cells = new Cell(11,13);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(1, 0, 2, 1, 2, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 0, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1);

            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(1, 1, 2,  1,  3,  0,  2);
            cells.SetCell(1, 1, 3,  2,  3,  1,  2);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1);
            cells.SetCell(0, 1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1);
        }
    }
    public class Cell
    {
        static List<List<Cell>> map = new List<List<Cell>>();

        public int value { get; set; }
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
        public Cell next { get; set; }
        public Cell previous { get; set; }

        public Cell() { }

        public Cell(int nRows, int nCol)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++)
            {
                List<Cell> newRow = new List<Cell>();
                map.Add(newRow);
                for (int col = 0; col < nCol; col++)
                {
                    Cell newCell = new Cell();
                    newCell.next = null;
                    newCell.previous = null;
                    newRow.Add(newCell);
                }
            }

        }
        public void SetCell(int xValue, int xRow, int xCol, int nextRow, int nextCol, int previousRow, int previousCol)
        {
            value = xValue;
            row = xRow;
            col = xCol;
            if (value == 1)
            {
                if(nextRow != -1)
                   map[row][col].next = map[nextRow][nextCol];
                if(previousRow != -1)
                   map[row][col].previous = map[previousRow][previousCol];
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be more flexible to use a "shortest path" graph algorithm like `A*` or `Dijkstra's algorithm` for your enemy's path finding.

That way your map definition just needs to encode where enemies start, where they are allowed to travel and where they want to go, and these things can change during the game.

E.g. your enemies could take a different route when something blocks their path, or do something (self destruct?) if they have no way to get to their destination.

Comment: For a real time application you don't want to run Dijkstra's.  You just need to add links the the map like I've done in my answer.

Comment: Hi yes I saw your answer. I think that allowing the user to edit maps and removing hard coding suggests the use of a path finding algorithm - which could be run when the map is edited and/or after real time map changes.

Comment: There is no need to find a path when you already know the path from previous moves.